# Solution to fully show tooltip on scrollable menubar

Tags: html, css, tooltip

[image]

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu bar and if I hover on an Item tooltip will show some text.

I am getting result A and I was hoping for a result like B where the tooltip is NOT half covered up by the dropdown menu.

I am assuming that since I have my span element is inside the anchor element,it is not possible for it to pop out of the dropdown menu or maybe
it's due to the overflow attribute but I'm not really sure how to fix or alter my code in order to achieve B, also I would not want to increase the width of the dropdown menu to achieve this,that is to say I don't want the tooltip text is restricted by the dropdown menu.

Is there a direction I can head to achieve what I am asking??

code is below :

HTML

```
<ul id='menu'>
<li>choose
    <ul>
      <li><a class="tooltip" href="">a<span class="tooltiptext">this is a</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="tooltip" href="">b<span class="tooltiptext">this is b</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="tooltip" href="">c<span class="tooltiptext">this is c</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="tooltip" href="">d<span class="tooltiptext">this is d</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS

```
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid grey;
    position:relative;
}
#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid grey;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    max-height:150px;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Try adding the tooltip to the nested LIs then apply "overflow: visible;" on the parent ULs

Answer (score 0):

Best results will be observed if you use Javascript. I've written up a brief example in CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/nn96zl4jl).

Set the containing `<ul>` element to `position: absolute`, have tooltip `<div>` elements outside of this element and initially `display: none`, write element ids that can be connected by a pattern (e.g. element id 'number1', tooltip id 'number1tooltip', 2...3...4 etc.), connect event listeners that can get the hovered target ('mouseenter', 'mouseleave') events, find the tooltip from the hovered target (concatenate 'tooltip' with id), set `display: inline` and use the `getBoundingClientRect()` to find out how to position it absolutely (see CodeSandbox methods).

GL.

Answer (score 0):

just make a small change in CSS

```
  #menu li:hover ul{
  overflow: visible;
  max-height:150px;
}
```

Your problem was caused because of overflow value as you see above. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsezy3kn/24/). Here are little docs about overflow value [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: I am going to need the scrollbar so still trying to adjust my code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I will focus on your problem. So in my opinion, it would be hard without javascript. I found an example like http://jsfiddle.net/vbddw4r0.